# Undo the rotation by keeping the rotated object in position

Tags: python, rotation

I am rotating an object about an arbitrary axis with a given angle using ([Link](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxnbGVubm11cnJheXxneDoyMTJiZTZlNzVlMjFiZTFi)) following rotation matrix:

```
 def rotate_object(self, direction_vector, origin_point, point_to_rotate, angle):

    angle = np.radians(angle)
    a, b, c = origin_point
    x, y, z = point_to_rotate

    if direction_vector == 0:
        u, v, w = [1.0, 0.0, 0.0] # Rotate in +x direction

    elif direction_vector == 1:
        u, v, w = [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]  # Rotate in +y direction

    elif direction_vector == 2:
        u, v, w = [-0.1027, -0.1525, 0.9829] # Rotate in +z direction

    cos = np.cos(angle)
    sin = np.sin(angle)

    qx = (a*(v**2 + w**2) -u*(b*v + c*w - u*x - v*y - w*z)) * (1-cos) + x*cos + (-c*v + b*w - w*y + v*z) * sin
    qy = (b*(u**2 + w**2) -v*(a*u + c*w - u*x - v*y - w*z)) * (1-cos) + y*cos + (c*u - a*w + w*x - u*z) * sin
    qz = (c*(u**2 + v**2) -w*(a*u + b*v - u*x - v*y - w*z)) * (1-cos) + z*cos + (-b*u + a*v - v*x + u*y) * sin

    return qx, qy, qz
```

The rotation of the object about a desired axis with a given angle works as expected. But I want to undo the coordinate system after every rotation to the original state by keeping the object on its rotated position. How could I do that?
Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Your function is rotating a 3D point around a 3D line. Both the point and the line are described in terms of cartesian coordinates in a coordinate system. The coordinate system is not rotating, the line is also not rotating. What is rotating is only the point. The output of the function is the new coordinates of the point in the coordinate system. So there no need to undo anything. I suggest you to use the function in the following way: call the function always with the same input except the angle, which should be increasing, then use or plot the different outputs.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Assume I have another line that is connected with the first rotated line after first rotation about `Z` axis. I want to rotate (independently from the first line) that line about `Y` axis. If I call the function with the same inputs expect angle, the second line moves in the same direction as the first line. Therefore I want to undo the axes, so that the second line moves in `Y` direction. Even if I select another direction vector e.g. ` u, v, w = [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]` it really does not move in the correct direction.

Comment: I guess you would like to animate an articulated model (like a robot arm or something like that). For that you need a hierarchy of transformations (the so called hierarchical model), where parent nodes pass their transform to Child nodes. For that you really need to use Matrices. Your function is technically correct, but it already applies the transform to the input point. For hiearchical models you would need to compose several transformations before applying them to the point. The function you have complicates doing such things.

Comment: I am not saying you can't doing hiearchical model animation with your function. I am saying matrices are a more convinient tool for this particular problem. So you still can find a way of doing what you want with your function.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two rotation axis: axis1 and axis2 which are 3D lines connected at a point (they intersect at a point).

Suppose the axis form a hierarchy, like the turret of a tank which can rotate around axis1 and the cannon mounted on the turret which can rotate around axis2.

The goal is to compute rotation of the cannon given the rotation of the turret or... compute rotation around axis2 given rotation around axis1.

Let's define your transform function as F(axis, angle, p)

Rotation around axis1 can be computed as F(axis1, angle1, p). Take into account that axis1 is "parent" of axis2. In our example that means that when turret rotates also the cannon rotates. So all points from turret AND cannon are rotated like F(axis1, angle1, p).

Rotation around axis2 can be defined as:

F(axis1, angle1, F(axis2, angle2, p))

That is a conposition of transforms in which we first apply rotation around axis2 and then around axis1. Which means that all points of the cannon are transformed first and then they transform according to turret transform.

If you follow this receipt, composition of F(a1,F(a2,F(a3, ...))), you will be able to animate hierarchical models using F.